# How to transform a non-uniform data into uniform data by non-linear transforms?

Tags: statistics, interpolation, data-analysis

Suppose we have a data set $x_i,y_i$, where $\delta_i = |x_i-x_{i-1}|$ is different, how can we transform this data sets into uniform forms, i.e., $\delta_i = |x_i-x_{i-1}|$ is same for all $i$ and do interpolation?

transform a no-nuniform data into uniform data

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly; you'll want to explain in more detail, and present your own work on the problem. In any event, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.